# NgFor index change class every 3 items. Math Problem?

Tags: angular, math

I have 3 CSS classes which colour a `mat-icon` which I use in an `NgFor` of news Items. I want the colours of each item to change on each item in blocks of 3. So I need the 1st and 4th to be the same class the 2nd and 5th and so on. The only way I can do this right now is like so:

```html
<mat-icon *ngIf="i == 0" class="news-icon-1">language</mat-icon>
<mat-icon *ngIf="i == 1" class="news-icon-2">language</mat-icon>
<mat-icon *ngIf="i == 2" class="news-icon-3">language</mat-icon>
<mat-icon *ngIf="i == 3" class="news-icon-1">language</mat-icon>
<mat-icon *ngIf="i == 4" class="news-icon-2">language</mat-icon>
<mat-icon *ngIf="i == 5" class="news-icon-3">language</mat-icon>
<mat-icon *ngIf="i == 6" class="news-icon-1">language</mat-icon>
<mat-icon *ngIf="i == 7" class="news-icon-2">language</mat-icon>
<mat-icon *ngIf="i == 8" class="news-icon-3">language</mat-icon>
```

There must be a better way to do this, probably using math but I'm not sure what that might be. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to assign a class at all. You can use the n-th selector in CSS directly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Thanks, that lead me to p:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background: red;
} If you want to write an answer I will accept it.

Comment: as I see it will not work, because elements are eliminated by `ngIf`. css selectors doesn't know about "hidden" elements and won't be able to determine order correcly

Comment: Yes I see that now having tried the CSS route. I am currently trying your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$index` to solve your problem

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let index = index;">
 <mat-icon *ngIf="i == index" class="news-icon-{{i%3 + 1)}}">language</mat-icon>
</ng-container>
```

or, if you need more control, you could use `ngClass`:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let index = index;">
 <mat-icon *ngIf="i == index" [ngClass]="{'news-icon-1': i%3==0, 'news-icon-2': i%3==1, 'news-icon-3': i%3==2}">language</mat-icon>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Messing with the class attribute affects the mat-icon classes and the icon stops showing.

Comment: take the 2nd solition. will work for sure

Comment: or `class="your-classes news-icon-{{i%3 + 1)}}"` will work sometimes

Comment: I am getting i%3 is NAN

Comment: you just need index and not $index. Update the answer and I will accept. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ah, sry. it should be `index` not '$index'. i ll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically speaking, you're looking for [remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder):

```
1 + (0 % 3) // 1
1 + (1 % 3) // 2
1 + (2 % 3) // 3
1 + (3 % 3) // 1
1 + (4 % 3) // 2
1 + (5 % 3) // 3
// …
```

You can combine this with using [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) to get the desired effect by building the class name dynamically using `1 + (i % 3)`.

That said, all of this is unnecessary here, and you can instead handle this [using CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) directly:

```
mat-icon:nth-child(3n) {
 // …
}

mat-icon:nth-child(3n + 1) {
 // …
}

mat-icon:nth-child(3n + 2) {
 // …
}
```

Comment: because of the *ngFor I could not get the CSS rules to work. Thanks for pointing this out though.